# I have CakePhp project source code but don't have database

Tags: php, cakephp

I have CakePhp project source code but don't have database. Is there anyway to generate database-tables from the application?

My database was corrupted/deleted. Please advise me. Thank you.

Comment: Run migrations, if there aren't any ask the company you've got the code base from.

Comment: What version of CakePHP is it? With version 1.x, there might be a schema file under the config folder.

Comment: Also, if there are any unit tests, you might be able to get at least some of the details from the fixtures.

Comment: We have purchased from the company couple of years ago. Now the company is no more. So is there anyway to get tables.